# Load emacs elisp library only if it is present

Tags: emacs, configuration-files

I have a standard .emacs file that I want to use on multiple machines. One some of the machines I am not able to load all of my elisp libraries.

Right now, I get this error on machines where, for example, `wc-mode-0.2.el` is not present:

```
Cannot open load file: wc-mode-0.2.el
```

Is there a way that I can make the .emacs file not error out at this point? Either by:

1. Checking to see if the library exists before I try to load it.
2. Catching the error condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `load` and `require` have a way of no signaling an error if a file is not found.

```
(load FILE &optional NOERROR NOMESSAGE NOSUFFIX MUST-SUFFIX)
(require FEATURE &optional FILENAME NOERROR)
```

So you can do this:

```
;; using load
(when (load "myfile.el" t)
       (do-my-thing))
;;using require
(when (require "myfeature" nil t)
       (do-my-thing))
```

Comment: you're missing the `NOERROR` args in your example.  E.g. `(require 'feature nil 'noerror)`.

Comment: really nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While @yorodm's answer is probably more correct (upvoted!), a form that I've been using for years is:

```el
;; load & configure myfeature if it's available
(cond ((locate-library "myfeature")
       (require 'myfeature)
       (setq myfeature-variable "stuff")
       (do-my-thing))
```